# The trouble with the paths in .Net Core application in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker

I have some problem. How to save in my .Net Core app into Docker container the file to a folder on the absolute path and not the relative path.

My files save into /var/lib/docker/overlay2/19564d0bf/merged/app/Images/vehicle, but to need saving into /mnt/app/files/Images/vehicle

Comment: What is `/mnt/app`? A mounted shared perhaps? Are you asking how to save something to the *host's* file system instead of the container's? If you already mounted the folder, why not use the absolute path you want in your code?

Comment: BTW this probably has nothing to do with .NET Core. This looks like a container configuration issue

Answer (score 0):

Use mount with docker run:

```
docker run -v /mnt/app/files/Images/vehicle:/YOUR_LOCAL_PATH imageName
```

Save file to YOUR_LOCAL_PATH, then you can find it at /mnt/app/files/Images/vehicle